# MySQL count consecutive dates for current streak

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a MySQL table with `timestamp` and `user` columns, I'd like to be able to count how many consecutive days (must end with today) records exist for a given user.

All of the examples on stackoverflow/google involve finding previous streaks, or counting total streaks, but I need to know about their **current** streak;

I can use this to find all days of which there are records for the day prior:

```
select date(start_of_votes.date_created)
from votes start_of_votes
left join votes previous_day
    on start_of_votes.username = previous_day.username
    and date(start_of_votes.date_created) - interval 1 day = date(previous_day.date_created)
where previous_day.id is not null
and start_of_votes.username = "bob"
group by date(start_of_votes.date_created) desc
```

But I need to only count ranges that include a record for today.

Per request, some sample data:

```
bob 2014-08-10 00:35:22
sue 2014-08-10 00:35:22
bob 2014-08-11 00:35:22
mike 2014-08-11 00:35:22
bob 2014-08-12 00:35:22
mike 2014-08-12 00:35:22
```

Today being Aug 12 2014:

`bob` has a streak of 3 days
`sue` has no current streak
`mike` has a streak of 2 days

This data is per-user, so I'll run a query for `bob` and get `3` as the result. I don't need a result broken down by user.

Comment: Couldn't you just keep a running total using a user variable + 1 and then limit the results by current day giving you a "how many consecutive days?"

Comment: can you add some relevant data?

Comment: Added some sample data

Comment: @xQbert If I could have "just" done something, I wouldn't have asked. If I'm missing something super basic that should have been obvious to me, it wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: My attempt was at offering a direction instead of exact syntax.  to me the problem was a logic and feature knowledge missing and not a syntax error thus why I provided direction and not a specific solution.... but since you appear to want more... see response below.

Comment: 'where previous day is not null' - so, in other words 'JOIN' !?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query keeps the streak count in a variable and as soon as there's a gap it resets the count to a large negative. It then returns the largest streak.

Depending on how many votes a user can have you might need to change `-99999` to a larger (negative) value.

```
select if(max(maxcount) < 0, 0, max(maxcount)) streak
from (
select 
  if(datediff(@prevDate, datecreated) = 1, @count := @count + 1, @count := -99999) maxcount,
  @prevDate := datecreated
  from votes v cross join 
    (select @prevDate := date(curdate() + INTERVAL 1 day), @count := 0) t1
  where username = 'bob'
  and datecreated <= curdate()
  order by datecreated desc
) t1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37129/6

**Update**

Another variation

```
select * from (
select datecreated, 
  @streak := @streak+1 streak, 
  datediff(curdate(),datecreated) diff
from votes 
cross join (select @streak := -1) t1
where username = 'bob'
and datecreated <= curdate()
order by datecreated desc
) t1 where streak = diff
order by streak desc limit 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6dd5b/20

Note, fiddle will only return correct streaks if run at the date of this post :)

**Update 2**

The query below works with tables that allow multiple votes per day by the same user by selecting from a derived table where duplicate dates are removed.

```
select * from (
  select date_created, 
  @streak := @streak+1 streak, 
  datediff(curdate(),date_created) diff
  from (
    select distinct date(date_created) date_created
    from votes where username = 'pinkpopcold'
  ) t1
  cross join (select @streak := -1) t2
  order by date_created desc
  ) 
t1 where streak = diff
order by streak desc limit 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fc6d/7

You may want to replace `select *` with `select streak + 1` depending on whether you want to include the 1st vote in the streak.

Comment: I'm not able to get either of these to work. For example, I have a user "dolly" who has voted today and two days ago, but not yesterday. It shows "streak 2, diff 2", and a user who has voted for the past four days, it shows no streak.

Comment: @helion3 i created a fiddle with the same scenario and it's working for me. maybe your db's curdate() isn't what you're expecting? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8716/1

Comment: Here's an example user: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5fc6d/1/0. Running this query I get: `2014-08-17 08:18:03 - 1 - 1`. The `curdate()` for the server is currently `2014-08-18`.

Comment: @helion3, I had assumed there could only be 1 vote per user per day. See update

Comment: @FuzzyTree hey man. I really liked your second update with the `select streak + 1`. In my case I tried to include a count of how many votes occurred at curdate() but I failed :( I tried adding COUNT at various places but this query is too complex for me. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Ando If you post a new question I'll take a look

Comment: I posted one and a fellow SOer answered it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic gist of it:

Create an ordered set by date using the query you started with and then wrap it with a running total to get the counts but limit the results to be just today.  I removed the username from the inner query so that it could be applied to the outer if needed, or return an entire set of everyone that matches today.  Note this fiddle only returns results on 8/12/2014 unless sample data is adjusted.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8554/21/0

USING:

```
Create table votes (
id int,
date_created date,
username varchar(10));

insert into votes (id, username,date_created) VALUES
(1, 'bob', '2014-08-10 00:35:22'),
(2, 'sue', '2014-08-10 00:35:22'),
(3, 'bob', '2014-08-11 00:35:22'),
(4, 'mike', '2014-08-11 00:35:22'),
(5, 'bob', '2014-08-12 00:35:22'),
(6, 'mike', '2014-08-12 00:35:22');
```

and then

```
SET @runtot:=0;

select SOVUN, SOVDC, 
  case when SOVUN = PDUN
  then @runtot:=@runtot+1
  else @runtot:=0 end as RunningTotal
FROM (

SELECT 
start_of_Votes.username SOVUN, 
Start_of_Votes.Date_Created SOVDC, 
previous_day.username PDUN,
Previous_day.date_created PDDC
from votes start_of_votes
left join votes previous_day
    on start_of_votes.username = previous_day.username
    and date(start_of_votes.date_created) - interval 1 day = date(previous_day.date_created)
order by SOVUN, SOVDC) B
```

Returning:

```
SOVUN   SOVDC                           RUNNINGTOTAL
bob     August, 10 2014 00:00:00+0000   0
bob     August, 11 2014 00:00:00+0000   1
bob     August, 12 2014 00:00:00+0000   2
mike    August, 11 2014 00:00:00+0000   0
mike    August, 12 2014 00:00:00+0000   1
sue     August, 10 2014 00:00:00+0000   0
```

Note you can't LIMIT by day without wrapping it in a sub query or the running total count will not work.  You can't apply the running total count earlier as the set must first be ordered.  Thus two nested sub queries are needed.

Comment: I'm not seeing where the query limits the result to streaks that include today? With my tests on real data, it's showing every vote record for each user with the running total (like your ex, which is fine, I can total them myself), but the counts are really confusing. I suppose it's my fault, I neglected to mention that a user might have up to six votes on a single day. The query counts each vote based on the number of votes that day, so if someone has 6 votes a day, it counts all 6, 6 times each. By the end of a week-long streak, one user has a run total of 132.