# Counting consecutive days for all items in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I'm trying to count consecutive days for all items. I've found how to count consecutive days [just for one item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272098/mysql-count-consecutive-dates-for-current-streak), sample data

```
bob 2014-08-10 00:35:22
sue 2014-08-10 00:35:22
bob 2014-08-11 00:35:22
mike 2014-08-11 00:35:22
bob 2014-08-12 00:35:22
mike 2014-08-12 00:35:22
```

would give me result for Bob like this:

```
date_created         | streak|
2014-08-10 00:35:22  |      3|
```

But I'd need to get it for all users like this:

```
date_created         | streak|username
2014-08-10 00:35:22  |      3|     Bob
2014-08-11 00:35:22  |      2|     Mike
```

I've been trying to modify sql from [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25273033/873453), but I just can not get it work. I'd be thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one thing you could do is self join the table to itself on consecutive days and count it. note I add one to the count because it wont count the first day

```
SELECT MIN(e.date_created) as date_created, e.username, COUNT(e.username) + 1 AS streak
FROM example e
LEFT JOIN example ee 
  ON e.username = ee.username 
 AND DATE(e.date_created) = DATE(DATE_ADD(ee.date_created, INTERVAL -1 DAY))
WHERE ee.username IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY e.username;
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93749/3)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've tested it and unfortunately, it doesn't work as it should. If you add values ('bob', '2014-08-05 00:35:22'),
('bob', '2014-08-06 00:35:22'), it will show Bob with date_created "August, 05 2014 00:35:22" and streak 4, which is incorrect, because that is not consecutive (Bob's days are 05, 06, 10, 11, 12)

Comment: @DropDropped can this be done in another programming language? I can write a query that will do it for you. but its not guarenteed to work.. what I mean is any sql variable that does row by row calculations can have incorrect values because mysql doesn't guarentee the order of evaluation. I have seen it not work before. which is why I usually steer away from those variables. I can make one for you. but it will not work every time

Comment: Thank you for your help. Finally, I've done the counting in PHP instead of SQL. If you'd like, you can write a query here anyway so I could accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can solve this with CTE as follows and here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c184a/13)

```
with ranks as
(
  select
    date,
    name,
    dateadd(day, -row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date), date) as rr
  from orders
),
cnt as
(
  select
    name,
    count(*) as ttl
  from ranks
  group by
    name,
    rr
)

select 
  min(date) as date,
  r.name,
  ttl
FROM ranks r
join cnt c
on r.name = c.name
where ttl > 1
group by
  r.name,
  ttl
```