# count consecutive days (streak) and number of records for current day

Tags: mysql

The following code was taken from another question on SO. [Original Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25273033/1617800)

I would like to count the number of consecutive days (Streak) with records since today AND also how many records were made today. I'm using this to send notifications. If a user submits a new record the same day, they should not get a second notification telling them that they are on a streak (they were made aware the first time they submitted a record for the current day).

I tried adding a `COUNT()` function before `@streak`, after the first `SELECT` and pretty much everywhere that seemed reasonable but this query is too complex for me to figure it out.

```
SELECT streak + 1 as realStreak
FROM (
SELECT dt, 
@streak := @streak+1 streak, 
datediff(curdate(),dt) diff
FROM (
SELECT distinct date(dt) dt
FROM glucose where uid = 1
) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @streak := -1) t2
ORDER BY dt desc
)
t1 where streak = diff
ORDER BY streak DESC LIMIT 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45d386/1/0

The result of the above should be:

```
realStreak | RecordsToday
3          |    3
```

Comment: May be same as this link,may be its helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272098/mysql-count-consecutive-dates-for-current-streak

Comment: Thanks @Hulk that is where i got the sql snippet... I referenced it in my question.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a subquery for the today check

```
SELECT streak + 1 as realStreak,cdt
FROM (
SELECT dt,
@streak := @streak+1 streak, 
datediff(curdate(),dt) diff
FROM (
SELECT distinct date(dt) dt
FROM gl where uid = 1
) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @streak := -1) t2
ORDER BY dt desc
)t1
JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(dt)=CURDATE() THEN 1 END) cdt FROM gl)x
where streak = diff
ORDER BY streak DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thanks! `Just add...` i wish it was that simple for me, too.