# Find period since last pause in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need to find the period without pause in days since last pause. 
I have a next table:

```
id | user |    date
-----------------------
 1 |  1   | 16.02.2017   
 1 |  1   | 15.02.2017
 1 |  1   | 14.02.2017
 1 |  1   | 13.02.2017
 1 |  1   | 10.02.2017
```

> Last pause: **10-13 February**
>
> Last period without pause: **4 days**

I tried to found the difference between day like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32346589/calculate-the-differences-between-two-rows-in-sql), but as result it was always `NULL`. And this is only first part. For second part I thought to use something like ranking, but don't know if it will work.

I plan to use it with PHP 7 + MySQL 5.6.

Comment: do you mean consecutive dates?

Comment: @McNets yes, right

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: just found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272098/mysql-count-consecutive-dates-for-current-streak) hopefully it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this sample:

```
create table if not exists myt(id int, dd date);
insert into myt values
(1, '2017-01-01'),
(1, '2017-01-02'),
(1, '2017-01-03'),
(1, '2017-01-04'),
(1, '2017-01-08'),
(1, '2017-01-09'),
(1, '2017-01-10');
```

First you should set a partition by consecutive days:

```
select id, dd, 
       if(@last_date = '1900-01-01' or datediff(dd, @last_date) = -1, @cn := @cn, @cn := +1) consecutive, 
       @last_date := dd
from
    (select @last_date := '1900-01-01', @cn := 0) x,
    (select id, dd
     from myt
     order by dd desc) y
;
```

This returns:

```
+----+---------------------+-------------+
| id | dd                  | consecutive |
+----+---------------------+-------------+
| 1  | 10.01.2017 00:00:00 |      0      |
| 1  | 09.01.2017 00:00:00 |      0      |
| 1  | 08.01.2017 00:00:00 |      0      |
+----+---------------------+-------------+
| 1  | 04.01.2017 00:00:00 |      1      |
| 1  | 03.01.2017 00:00:00 |      1      |
| 1  | 02.01.2017 00:00:00 |      1      |
| 1  | 01.01.2017 00:00:00 |      1      |
+----+---------------------+-------------+
```

After you set a partition, then get MAX and MIN date for each partition:

```
select id, min(dd) as ini, max(dd) as fin, datediff(max(dd), min(dd)) as Days
from (
        select id, dd, 
               if(@last_date = '1900-01-01' or datediff(dd, @last_date) = -1, @cn := @cn, @cn := +1) consecutive, 
               @last_date := dd
        from
            (select @last_date := '1900-01-01', @cn := 0) x,
            (select id, dd
             from myt
             order by dd desc) y
    ) z
group by consecutive
;
```

Result:

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| id |         ini         |         fin         | Days |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| 1  | 08.01.2017 00:00:00 | 10.01.2017 00:00:00 |   2  |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| 1  | 01.01.2017 00:00:00 | 04.01.2017 00:00:00 |   3  |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+------+
```

Check it: http://rextester.com/XMIX80360

Answer (score 1):

Try this query. It will find all pauses -

```
SELECT curr_date, prev_date FROM (
  SELECT t1.date curr_date, MAX(t2.date) prev_date FROM periods t1
    LEFT JOIN periods t2
      ON t1.date > t2.date
    GROUP BY t1.date) t
WHERE DATEDIFF(curr_date, prev_date) > 1
```

The result is:

```
13-Feb-17   10-Feb-17
```

Then add condition/LIMIT to get only one row.

Comment: Works, but doesn't show if user is now in one of pauses.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to write general query like,

```
select count(distinct t1.`date`) from period t1 left join period t2 ON t2.user = t1.user and t1.`date` - INTERVAL 1 DAY = t2.date where t2.id is null
```

Can you try this query once, 
it should work, I have used it in my almost same case.

Answer (score 0):

This query will return the latest hole:

```
select
  m.`date`,
  min(m1.`date`) as next_date,
  datediff(min(m1.`date`), m.`date`)+1 as diff
from
  mytable m left join mytable m1
  on m.`date`<m1.`date`
group by
  m.`date`
having
  datediff(min(m1.`date`), m.`date`)>1
order by
  m.`date` desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query:

```sql
SELECT MIN(`date`) AS date_start,
       MAX(`date`) AS date_end,
       MAX(days_diff) AS pause_days,
       COUNT(*) + 1 AS period_without_pays
FROM (
   SELECT id, user, `date`, 
          DATE_SUB(`date`, INTERVAL rn DAY) AS group_date,
          DATEDIFF(`date`, COALESCE(prevDate, `date`)) AS days_diff
   FROM (       
      SELECT t1.id, t1.user, t1.`date`, 
             @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
             (SELECT t2.`date`
              FROM mytable AS t2        
              WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t1.user = t2.user AND t1.`date` > t2.`date`
              ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1) AS prevDate
      FROM mytable AS t1
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) AS v
      ORDER BY `date`) AS t) AS x
GROUP BY id, user, group_date, days_diff
HAVING SUM(days_diff) > 0
```

returns:

```
date_start date_end   pause_days  period_without_pays
-----------------------------------------------------
2017-02-14 2017-02-16 1           4
2017-02-13 2017-02-13 3           2
```

- The row with `pause_days > 1` returns the start date of the pause along with the number of days.
- The row with `pause_days = 1` returns the start / end dates of an island of consecutive records having consecutive dates along with the count of these dates.

**Note**: The above query works with the sample data provided. You may have to tweak the query a little bit so as to adjust it to the complexity of the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SET @dateDiff=NULL;SET @dateDiff2='';
SELECT diff.secondDate AS fromDate,diff.initialDate AS toDate, diff.dateDiffR FROM (
SELECT d.date AS initialDate,@dateDiff AS secondDate,IF(@dateDiff IS NULL,@dateDiff:=d.date,0) AS try,
IF(DATE(@dateDiff)!=DATE(d.date),DATEDIFF(d.date,@dateDiff),NULL) AS dateDiffR,
IF(@dateDiff!=@dateDiff2,@dateDiff2:=@dateDiff,0) AS try1,
IF(DATE(@dateDiff)!=DATE(d.date),@dateDiff:=d.date,NULL) AS assign FROM
(SELECT b.date FROM mytable b)d ) diff WHERE diff.dateDiffR>0
```

it will give you the date difference with its date range. If you get negative count then swap the dates on parameters' for DATEDIFF;

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I adapted little bit query from @McNets:

```
select user, min(dd) as ini, max(dd) as fin, datediff(max(dd), min(dd))+1 as Days, consecutive
from (
    select user,dd, 
           if(@last_date = curdate() or datediff(dd, @last_date) >= -1, @cn := @cn, @cn := @cn+1) consecutive,
           @last_date := dd
    from
        (select @last_date := curdate(), @cn := 0) x,
        (select user, date as dd
         from myt
         where user = %id
         order by dd desc) y
 ) z
group by consecutive 
order by CAST(consecutive AS UNSIGNED)
```

I added filter by user, changed cause to '>= -1' to accept time usage, added number of the serie and changed initial date from '1900-01-01' to  CURDATE() function (i don't see any influence to query result from this action).

Now using number of the series can find the longest series and its dates.